# How would I back a bunch of class properties with a dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, objective-c-runtime

I have a class that holds attributes in a dictionary where the keys are well defined.  I would like to replace this attribute dictionary with a class, let's call it AttributeSet.  Where there were defined keys:

```
extern NSString *const Foo;
```

I would like to have properties:

```
@interface AttributeSet : NSObject

@property(strong) NSString *Foo;

...a ton more

@end
```

I would actually like the AttributeSet object to use a dictionary behind the scenes because for backwards compatibility reasons.  So when this happens:

```
attributeSet.Foo = @"bar";
```

I actually want this to happen:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSString *)foo {
    self.attributes[Foo] = foo; //Foo is the extern variable Foo
}
```

but I don't want to have to define getters and setters for *all* of the properties.

I know that I can use key-value observing but that will 1) require me to have a mapping of (property name) @"Foo" --> (variable name) Foo and 2) result in *both* the property being set *and* the dictionary value being set when in reality I just want the dictionary to be set.

I know that I can do something like this: https://github.com/iosptl/ios6ptl/blob/master/ch28/Person/Person/Person.m
but that would 1) still require me to have a mapping and 2) require me to have an @dynamic for every property.

Is there a more automatic way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003780

Comment: What's wrong with defining all the setters and getters? Just a few minutes work, and it will work just fine. Better than being "smart".

Comment: I actually ended up writing a script to generate the methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob Napier's example is a good option; the compiler's going to generate accessors for you unless you tell it not to, and the way you tell it that is with the `@dynamic` directive.

Another option would be automated code generation: write a script to emit ObjC code for your setters.

The third that I can think of is [overwriting the accessors during runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664586/override-all-setters-and-getters-of-a-subclass). In your class's `+initialize`, you can get the list of its properties from the runtime library and use `class_replaceMethod()` to insert your own accessors that use your dictionary instead of the ivars. This will require some string mangling to get the accessor names and keys from each other.

Here's a gist with a demo of that last option: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/4fb874b15449ee7fd7e8

Comment: I ended up writing a script to do it as you suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To use the dynamically-generated accessor approach, as illustrated in the `Person` code you linked, without requiring `@dynamic`, you can declare the properties in a category on your class rather than the class itself:

```
@interface AttributeSet : NSObject

// ... no properties here ...

@end

@interface AttributeSet (YourPropertiesCategoryName)

@property(strong) NSString *Foo;

...a ton more

@end
```

The compiler will auto-synthesize properties declared in the class itself or in a class extension (which looks like a category with no category name), but not for a category.

Note that you don't need to and shouldn't provide an implementation for the category. (If you do, the compiler will complain about the lack of implementation for the properties. It won't auto-synthesize them, but you'll still need to use `@dynamic` to silence the warnings.)

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of time, I think I've come up with quite the extensible solution for you. All it requires of you is to simply create your objects using the following helper class, like this:

```
#import "DictionaryBackedObject.h"

extern NSString *const foo;
NSString *const foo = @"Foo";

@interface Foo : NSObject 

@property NSString *foo;

@end

@implementation Foo
@end

int main() {
    Foo *object = [DictionaryBackedObject dictionaryBackedObjectOfType:[Foo class]
                                                   backingDictionary:@{ foo: @"Bar" }
                                                             mutable:NO];

    NSLog(@"%@", [object foo]);
}
```

Note: This implementation is far from perfect, and it does use the 'dreaded' `dlsym` API, meaning, that you cannot strip your symbols from the executable should you wish to use this class. Also, it may cause rejection should this be submitted to the app store. There are other ways to automatically determine the key to use along with the dictionary, however, should you wish to find a workaround.

This implementation does support struct properties, as well as weak, copy, and atomic ones as well. It will be significantly slower than setting the property on a normal object, as this goes through objective-c's forwarding API (required to support struct returns).

Hopefully this helps you out, I certainly had a lot of fun making it.

**DictionaryBackedObject.h**

```
@interface DictionaryBackedObject : NSObject

+(id) dictionaryBackedObjectOfType:(Class) kls backingDictionary:(NSDictionary *) dictionary mutable:(BOOL) isMutable;

@end
```

**DictionaryBackedObject.m**

```
#import "DictionaryBackedObject.h"

#include <stdalign.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

@import ObjectiveC.runtime;
@import ObjectiveC.message;

__attribute__((noinline))
static SEL property_getGetterSelector(objc_property_t property) {
    char *getter = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "G");
    if (getter) {
        SEL result = sel_registerName(getter);

        free(getter);

        return result;
    }

    return sel_registerName(property_getName(property));
}

__attribute__((noinline))
static SEL property_getSetterSelector(objc_property_t property) {
    char *setter = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "S");
    if (setter) {
        SEL result = sel_registerName(setter);

        free(setter);

        return result;
    }

    char buffer[512];
    char propertyName[512];

    strncpy(propertyName, property_getName(property), 512);
    propertyName[0] = toupper(propertyName[0]);

    snprintf(buffer, 512, "set%s", propertyName);

    return sel_registerName(buffer);
}

struct objc_property_attributes_t {
    union {
        struct {
            int nonatomic : 1;
            int copy      : 1;
            int weak      : 1;
            int strong    : 1;
        };

        int memory_mode;
    };

    int is_readonly;
    int is_dynamic;
};

static inline BOOL property_isAttributeNull(objc_property_t property, const char *attr) {
    void *value = property_copyAttributeValue(property, attr);
    BOOL results = value == NULL;

    free(value);

    return results;
}

static struct objc_property_attributes_t property_getPropertyAttributes(objc_property_t property) {
    struct objc_property_attributes_t attrs;

    attrs.nonatomic = !property_isAttributeNull(property, "N");
    attrs.copy      = !property_isAttributeNull(property, "C");

    attrs.strong    = attrs.copy || !property_isAttributeNull(property, "&");
    attrs.weak      = !property_isAttributeNull(property, "W");

    attrs.is_readonly = !property_isAttributeNull(property, "R");
    attrs.is_dynamic = !property_isAttributeNull(property, "D");

    return attrs;
}

static objc_property_t class_getPropertyForSelector(Class kls, SEL cmd) {
#define VALID_PROPERTY(property) \
    (property != NULL && (property_getGetterSelector(property) == cmd || property_getSetterSelector(property) == cmd))

    const char *selName = sel_getName(cmd);

    objc_property_t results = class_getProperty(kls, selName);
    if (VALID_PROPERTY(results))
        return results;

    if (strstr(selName, "set") == selName) {
        char lowercaseSel[512];
        strncpy(lowercaseSel, strstr(selName, "set"), 512);
        lowercaseSel[0] = tolower(lowercaseSel[0]);

        results = class_getProperty(kls, lowercaseSel);

        if (VALID_PROPERTY(results)) return results;
    }

    // Easy paths exhausted, go the 'hard' way of looping over all of the properties available
    results = NULL;

    unsigned propertyCount = 0;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(kls, &propertyCount);

    for (unsigned propertyIndex = 0; propertyIndex < propertyCount; propertyIndex++) {
        if (VALID_PROPERTY(properties[propertyIndex])) {
            results = properties[propertyIndex];
            break;
        }
    }

    free(properties);

    return results;
#undef VALID_PROPERTY
}

@implementation DictionaryBackedObject

-(id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *) dictionary mutable:(BOOL) isMutable {
    return nil;
}

+(Class) dictionaryBackedSubclassOfClass:(Class) kls {
    @synchronized (kls) {
        NSString *className = [NSStringFromClass(kls) stringByAppendingFormat:@"_dictionaryBacked"];
        Class subclass = Nil;

        if ((subclass = NSClassFromString(className))) {
            return subclass;
        }

        subclass = objc_allocateClassPair(kls, [className UTF8String], 0);

        class_addIvar(subclass, "_backingDictionary", sizeof(NSDictionary *), _Alignof(NSDictionary *), @encode(NSDictionary *));
        class_addIvar(subclass, "_backingDictionaryIsMutable", sizeof(NSNumber *), _Alignof(NSNumber *), @encode(NSNumber *));

        unsigned propertyCount = 0;
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(kls, &propertyCount);

        for (unsigned i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];
            char *type = property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T");

            SEL getterSel = property_getGetterSelector(property);
            SEL setterSel = property_getSetterSelector(property);

            char getterTypeBuffer[512];
            snprintf(getterTypeBuffer, 512, "%s@:", type);

            char setterTypeBuffer[512];
            snprintf(setterTypeBuffer, 512, "v@:%s", type);

            NSUInteger typeSize;
            NSUInteger typeAlignment;

            NSGetSizeAndAlignment(type, &typeSize, &typeAlignment);
            BOOL isStret = (typeSize * CHAR_BIT) > (WORD_BIT * 2);

            class_addMethod(subclass, getterSel, isStret ? _objc_msgForward_stret : _objc_msgForward , getterTypeBuffer);
            class_addMethod(subclass, setterSel, _objc_msgForward, setterTypeBuffer);

            free(type);
        }

        free(properties);

        Ivar backingDictionaryIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(subclass, "_backingDictionary");
        Ivar backingDictionaryMutableIvar = class_getInstanceVariable(subclass, "_backingDictionaryIsMutable");

        class_addMethod(subclass, @selector(forwardingTargetForSelector:), imp_implementationWithBlock(^id (id self) {
            return nil;
        }), "@@:");

        class_addMethod(subclass, @selector(forwardInvocation:), imp_implementationWithBlock(^void (id self, NSInvocation *invocation) {
            SEL _cmd = [invocation selector];
            objc_property_t property = class_getPropertyForSelector([self class], _cmd);

            if (property == NULL) {
                [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
                return;
            }

            BOOL isGetter = (_cmd == property_getGetterSelector(property));
            struct objc_property_attributes_t attributes = property_getPropertyAttributes(property);

            NSString *propertyType = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFStringCreateWithCStringNoCopy(
                NULL, property_copyAttributeValue(property, "T"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8, NULL
            );

            NSUInteger propertySize;
            NSGetSizeAndAlignment([propertyType UTF8String], &propertySize, NULL);

            void *dlsymKey = dlsym(RTLD_MAIN_ONLY, property_getName(property));
            id dictionaryKey = *(__unsafe_unretained id *) dlsymKey;

            NSMutableDictionary *backingDictionary = object_getIvar(self, backingDictionaryIvar);
            NSNumber *isMutable = object_getIvar(self, backingDictionaryMutableIvar);

            // Performing synchronization on nil is a no-op, see objc_sync.mm:306.
            @synchronized (attributes.nonatomic ? nil : self) {
                if (isGetter) {
                    id value = backingDictionary[dictionaryKey];

                    if (attributes.strong) {
                        [invocation setReturnValue:&value];
                    } else if (attributes.weak) {
                        value = [value nonretainedObjectValue];

                        [invocation setReturnValue:&value];
                    } else {
                        void *buffer = alloca(propertySize);
                        [value getValue:buffer];

                        [invocation setReturnValue:buffer];
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((attributes.is_readonly || ![isMutable boolValue])) {
                        [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
                        return;
                    }

                    id dictionaryValue = nil;
                    void *newValue = alloca(propertySize);
                    [invocation getArgument:newValue atIndex:2];

                    if (attributes.strong) {
                        dictionaryValue = (__bridge id) newValue;

                        if (attributes.copy) {
                            dictionaryValue = [dictionaryValue copy];
                        }
                    } else if (attributes.weak) {
                        dictionaryValue = [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:(__bridge id) newValue];
                    } else {
                        dictionaryValue = [NSValue valueWithBytes:newValue objCType:[propertyType UTF8String]];
                    }

                    if (dictionaryValue == nil) {
                        [backingDictionary removeObjectForKey:dictionaryKey];
                    } else {
                        [backingDictionary setObject:dictionaryValue forKey:dictionaryKey];
                    }
                }
            }
        }), "v@:@");

        class_addMethod(subclass, @selector(initWithDictionary:mutable:), imp_implementationWithBlock(^id (id self, NSDictionary *dictionary, BOOL mutable) {
            object_setIvar(self, backingDictionaryIvar, dictionary);
            object_setIvar(self, backingDictionaryMutableIvar, @(mutable));

            return self;
        }), "@@:@c");

        objc_registerClassPair(subclass);

        return subclass;
    }
}

+(id) dictionaryBackedObjectOfType:(Class)kls backingDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary mutable:(BOOL)isMutable {
    Class subclass = [self dictionaryBackedSubclassOfClass:kls];

    return [[subclass alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary mutable:isMutable];
}

@end
```

Comment: /me offers secret wacko-overkill-runtime-hacking club salute